# SDWebImage update giving error in IOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to use SDWebImage library for my project. I copied all the files. I have imported #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h" But when I tried to use the below code.

```
 [weakArticleImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] placeholderImage:placeHolderImage
                 success:^(UIImage *image) 
                    {
                          weakArticleImage.image =   [self image:image WithRoundedCornersRadius:10];
                          CGRect tempFrame;
                          tempFrame   =   weakArticleImage.frame;
                          tempFrame.size =   [self resizeImage:weakArticleImage.image constrainedToHeight:[self rowHeightForSectionArticleViewAtIndexPath:indexPath]-20 andWidth:70];
                          tempFrame.origin.y  =   ([self rowHeightForSectionArticleViewAtIndexPath:indexPath]-CGRectGetHeight(weakArticleImage.frame))/2;
                           weakArticleImage.frame =   tempFrame;
                    }
                                                  failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                                      nil;
                                                  }]
```

> No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector
>   'setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:'

What am i missing

Comment: Somewhere you might be using setImageWithURL:... instead of sd_setImageWithURL:...